# how can I get a recordId then it returns the list of fields included in the correponding Sobject

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

This is my code :

```
public static List <String> getFields (Id IdRecord) {
 SObjectType  objType = ((SObject) (Type.forName('Schema.' + IdRecord).newInstance())).getSObjectType();
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
  List<String> Fields = new List<String>();
  
    for (SObjectField field : schemaFieldMap.values()){
        
        Fields.add(Field.getDescribe().getName());
        
    }
    system.debug('fields=' +Fields);
    return Fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To return more than one value, you need a "wrapper":

```
public class sObjectDescribe {
  public String sObjectName;
  public String[] fields = new String[0];
}
public static sObjectDescribe getFields(Id recordId) {
  sObjectDescribe result = new sObjectDescribe();
  result.sObjectName = recordId.getSObjectType()+'';
  for(sObjectField field: recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
    result.fields.add(field+'');
  }
  return result;
}
```

Notice how we can use string concatenation to convert the object and field names without getting a describe. Also see how we can get the sObjectType directly from the Id, you don't need to call Type.forName or anything here.