# Retrieve field details based on Record API Name

Tags: apex, dynamic

When I'm trying to retrieve the fields baes on a record, I get this error :Line: 8, Column: 1
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.

and This is my code :

```
public static String getListOfFields(Id recordAPIName){
        Map<string, string> fieldList = new Map<string, string>();
        if(!String.isEmpty(recordAPIName)){
            Map<String, String> mapField = new Map<String, String>();
            Map<string,SObjectField> lstFields = 
                schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(recordAPIName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

            for(String str: lstFields.keySet()){
                mapField.put(str, lstFields.get(str).getDescribe().getLabel());                
            }
            System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(mapField));
            return JSON.serializePretty(mapField);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please can anyone help me ! Thinks for advance :))

Comment: Error is because getGlobalDescribe returns a Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> so when you are putting a record type name in it it returns a null value (.getDescribe())  on null is causing exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I get a recordId then it returns the list of fields included in the correponding Sobject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348629/how-can-i-get-a-recordid-then-it-returns-the-list-of-fields-included-in-the-corr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the record Id in the parameter to the method **getListOfFields** instead of the object name. If you pass the object name to this method instead of the Id then it will work properly.
If you want to pass the Record Id as the parameter to this method then you need to get the object name from the record Id first using following.

```
String sObjName = recId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```

Note: If recId is the record Id which you have passed as a parameter to the method.

Then get the details of the object using following line.
`Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();`

Let me know if you need additional details.
The code will be as follows.

```
public static String getListOfFields(Id recordId){
String recordAPIName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
Map<string, string> fieldList = new Map<string, string>();
if(!String.isEmpty(recordAPIName)){
    Map<String, String> mapField = new Map<String, String>();
    Map<string,SObjectField> lstFields = 
        schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(recordAPIName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(String str: lstFields.keySet()){
        mapField.put(str, lstFields.get(str).getDescribe().getLabel());                
    }
    System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(mapField));
    return JSON.serializePretty(mapField);
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer ! plz can you tell me where exactly  added these ?

Comment: I have updated the comment with code snippet. Please check.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the return type in the above code is String and not the List<String>.

Comment: Isnt current question and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348629/how-can-i-get-a-recordid-then-it-returns-the-list-of-fields-included-in-the-corr same ?

Comment: I think they are same. the only difference is in method return type. One of these questions needs to be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Kalpana thanks ! it works well

Comment: Could you please accept the answer and mark it as resolved. Thanks!